# php how to get typeID and ProductID for cart

Tags: php, function, shopping-cart

hey im trying to make a shopping cart using php iv talked to other students in my class and they think for some reason there is something wrong with my getProductByTypeId query... it picks up everything except my ProductID from the database.

Below is my function...

```
function getProductsByTypeID($TypeID){

//pull in global connection
global $connection;

//execute query to select all product types
$query="select * from product where TypeID = ".$TypeID;
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
testQuery($result);

//return list of customers
return $result;
}
```

Comment: What results are you getting back?

Comment: You should include the code for `testQuery()` so we can see what it does. Also, there is a tag called Homework that you can pop on if you want guidance more than a straight answer. Sometimes hints are better for you so that you learn it for yourself and truly understand the answer.